# How to get all form fields except hidden and submit button in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, field

```html
<form class="myform" id="myform">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="input_1" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="input_2 "name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  Agree:<br>
  <input type="radio" id="input_3 "name="agree" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can i get all form fields by name in a select/dropdown and return the id on selection?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and what was the problem with it? Are these fields dynamically created so that it prevents you from adding a static select with these fields? If dynamically created, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` on your form, and then just generator the dictionary you would need for your selector:

```js
let selector_vals = {};
let input_select = $("#input_select");
$("#myform input:not([type=submit])").each(function(idx, elem) {
    selector_vals[elem.name] = "#" + elem.id;
    input_select.append(new Option(elem.name,"#" + elem.id));
});

console.log(selector_vals);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Form Items<br/>
<select id="input_select"></select>

<form class="myform" id="myform">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="input_1" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="input_2 "name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  Agree:<br>
  <input type="radio" id="input_3 "name="agree" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That is exactly what i need, now how can i append it to the <select>?

e.g 
<select>
<option value="elem.id">elem.name</option>
</select>

Comment: @Usman Added the code to generate the `select`, you can remove `selector_vals` if you don't need to keep track of the IDs since the loop already adds the `option`s directly to the `select`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands -

For getting specific input fields of a form -

```
var p = $('input[type=text]')
```

Then on your dropdown element with ID as '#select' use -

```
$('#select').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
```

where 'p' is nothing but all the elements you got from jquery selector above.

Though I can not really help you more here. Please post the code and reframe your question.